# Building Qt 4.8 with QtDBus support

Tags: qt, homebrew, configure, dbus, qtdbus

I try to compile Qt from sources, everything goes ok(more or less), except dbus part.

> ./configure -v -opensource -dbus-linked -arch i386

Configure shows this error:

> 1 error generated.
>   make: *** [dbus.o] Error 1
>   D-Bus disabled.
>   The QtDBus module cannot be enabled because libdbus-1 version 0.93 was not found.
>    Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to ./configure to see the final report.
>    If you believe this message is in error you may use the continue
>    switch (-continue) to ./configure to continue.

I installed dbus 1.6 with Homebrew, but configure tool can't see it. Lib and headers are located in /usr/local/Cellar/d-bus/1.6.18. How to point configure to this location?

Platform is OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem seems to be that, its not finding the dbus libraries.

Set the path of the library and the includes when you configure, something like this, assuming your dbus libraries and includes are in
/usr/local/Cellar/d-bus/1.6.18

> ./configure -v -opensource -arch i386 -dbus-linked -L/usr/local/Cellar/d-bus/1.6.18/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/d-bus/1.6.18/include

where -I will tell qmake to include headers from that path and -L to link to the dbus libraries.